# Using react in node.js express, mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, babeljs

Most likely, this question has already been asked by someone, but since I could not find information on this issue on my own, I am asking the community for help
The question is as follows:
How to add `react` to an existing project on `node.js`, `express`, `mysql`, WITHOUT using assemblers (`webpack` and others).I would also like some links to how to work in `node.js` with `babel`(transpile `babel` files to js and so on), creating the correct project hierarchy when using `react`, `babel`, and other dependencies with them.

PS. Sorry, if such a question already exists, I'm just delving into it all

Answer (score 0):

Since React is a library, the good news is you can use it straight away without any assemblers. Using npm install react and react-dom is all you need to get started, but without babel you won't be able to use JSX or any other unsupported modern JS. Downside is that without an assembler like webpack, getting everything to compile nicely is alot of extra work. If you have a bunch of .js files and want to use babel...well, it would really save you a lot of work to just learn webpack and configure it yourself (or use create-react-app). Otherwise, there's plenty of resources online about how to configure those things without a compiler.